# Extract multiple text string to form new row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert arrays within a row of csv into multiple rows. Currently the data is like this

```
test = result['properties.techniques'].dropna()
print(test)
```

['T1078','T1036']
['T1036']

I can add the following line to extract the individual items -

```
test = result['properties.techniques'].dropna()
techniques = result['properties.techniques'].str.extract(r"(T[0-9]{4})").dropna()[0]
print(techniques )
```

T1078
T1036

This however will only extract one string per row.

How do I ensure that all data is converted into a new row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .explode():

```
techniques = result.explode("properties.techniques").reset_index(drop=True)
print(techniques)
```

Output:

```
  properties.techniques
0                 T1078
1                 T1036
2                 T1036
```